# In javascript, I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a regex replace only the capture and not the match

Tags: javascript, regex

The following function is meant to remove random articles (parts of speech) from the text. Eventually the percentages will be user-adjustable, and the regex more sophisticated to catch word boundaries better, etc. It is replacing (and about 50/50), but it's also squashing the spaces (which are matched, but not captured). I think I'm being really bone-headed here but I can't figure out the proper syntax... can anyone help?

```
function posArticles(t) {
   var text = t;
   var re = / (a|the|an) /g;    
   var rArray;

   text = text.replace(re, function(_, m) {
       if (Math.floor(Math.random()*101) < 50) return '';
       else return m;
   });

   return text;
}
```

I realize that this has to do with the positional/optional arguments to the anon function, but I can't figure out which is the match and which is the capture and so forth.

Comment: That's how `.replace()` works: it does replace the whole match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realize that this has to do with the positional/optional arguments
>   to the anon function, but I can't figure out which is the match and
>   which is the capture and so forth.

First argument passed to your callback function is whole match (ie: `_ = ' the '`). Next argument are your captured groups (`m = 'the'`). Callback function is replacing whole match, so if you are including spaces in your expresion, they will also be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways you could do this, but I think your best bet is to use `\b` – a zero-width match for a "word boundary." That guarantees that you're getting "the" and not "there" or whatever, but doesn't match the spaces around it.

Thus, use `re = /\b([Aa]n?|[Tt]he)\b/;`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Math.floor(Math.random()*101) < 50) return ' ';
```

return a space instead of empty string :)

Comment: I think I really am being a bonehead. I had worried about when I added commas, but you never follow an article with a comma anyway.

Comment: try a simple solution (such as mine), run it over some of your sample input and see how it goes. if it does not work, let us know the edge and corner cases it fails on and we can go from there.